# Unable to load DLL on Heroku (Java)

Tags: java, c++, heroku, dll, java-native-interface

I want to call method from C++ via JNI. For this purpose I need to use system method System.loadLibrary.

Firstly, I tried to make it on localhost. I encountered with problems sort of "UnsatisfiedLinkError: not found DLL in java.library.path". Solution of this problem is class NativeUtils from this guide http://adamheinrich.com/blog/2012/how-to-load-native-jni-library-from-jar/ . And it perfectly works on localhost.

But when I deploy it on heroku I have a error "invalid ELF header (possible cause: endianness mismatch)".

How can I cope with it?

Comment: Does Heroku work with Windows systems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku servers are based on `Linux`, while your `DLL` works only on windows. This is why you got the error, and the solution is to make a `Linux` shared library. I'd recommend configuring a virtual machine with the Linux flavor that your Heroku instance has, build your library there, and use that in you repository instead of the DLL.

**Edit:** I found an article that might help you compile the library directly on the Heroku instance: http://www.saintsjd.com/2014/05/12/run-vendored-binaries-on-heroku.html

Comment: It was done of me:)
Maybe you know if it possible to compile .so with visual c++ compiler on windows? Or way without virtual machine:)